# fabricjs IText- Varied LineHeight

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a syntax that will allow for varied line heights (lineHeight) within one IText object? I've attempted to do this by adding lineHeight to the styles property, but it doesn't seem to be interpreting the different lineHeight.

```
styles: {
0: {
  0: { textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: 80, lineHeight: 1 },
  1: { textBackgroundColor: 'red', lineHeight: 1  }
},
```

Rendered with a lineHeight = 1:
http://jsfiddle.net/xmfw65qg/44/

Rendered at lineHeight = 2.5:
http://jsfiddle.net/xmfw65qg/43/

Note, they render identically and do not interpret the line height. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: It changes on the whole paragraph, but maybe it's not what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/xmfw65qg/45/

Answer (score 2):

Once there was an "unsupported feature" that allowed you to set the fontSize of the newline character to a big fontSize to emulate a higher lineHeight.

Now with code refactoring this procedure does not work anymore.

You can still

1) update to latest fabricjs version

2) override the _getLineHeight() the method as in the snippet

3) set in your style object a big fontSize for the last character in the line.

the override method consist to extend the for loop from "1 to < len" to "1 to = len" and nothing else.

```js
var text = {"type":"i-text","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":1,"top":1,"width":230.05,"height":235.94,"fill":"#333","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"lorem ipsum\ndolor\nsit Amet\nconsectetur","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.16,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","styles":{"0":{"0":{"fill":"red","fontSize":20,"fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"1":{"fill":"red","fontSize":30,"fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"2":{"fill":"red","fontSize":40,"fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"3":{"fill":"red","fontSize":50,"fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"4":{"fill":"red","fontSize":60,"fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"6":{"textBackgroundColor":"yellow"},"7":{"textBackgroundColor":"yellow"},"8":{"textBackgroundColor":"yellow"},"9":{"textBackgroundColor":"yellow","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"11":{"fontSize":80}},"1":{"0":{"textDecoration":"underline"},"1":{"textDecoration":"underline","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""},"2":{"fill":"green","fontStyle":"italic","textDecoration":"underline"},"3":{"fill":"green","fontStyle":"italic","textDecoration":"underline"},"4":{"fill":"green","fontStyle":"italic","textDecoration":"underline","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal"}},"2":{"0":{"fill":"blue","fontWeight":"bold"},"1":{"fill":"blue","fontWeight":"bold"},"2":{"fill":"blue","fontWeight":"bold","fontFamily":"Helvetica","fontSize":40,"fontStyle":""},"4":{"fontFamily":"Courier","textDecoration":"line-through"},"5":{"fontFamily":"Courier","textDecoration":"line-through"},"6":{"fontFamily":"Courier","textDecoration":"line-through"},"7":{"fontFamily":"Courier","textDecoration":"line-through","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""}, "8":{"fontSize":100}},"3":{"0":{"fontFamily":"Impact","fill":"#666","textDecoration":"line-through"},"1":{"fontFamily":"Impact","fill":"#666","textDecoration":"line-through"},"2":{"fontFamily":"Impact","fill":"#666","textDecoration":"line-through"},"3":{"fontFamily":"Impact","fill":"#666","textDecoration":"line-through"},"4":{"fontFamily":"Impact","fill":"#666","textDecoration":"line-through","fontSize":40,"fontWeight":"normal","fontStyle":""}}}};


fabric.IText.prototype._getHeightOfLine = function(ctx, lineIndex) {
      if (this.__lineHeights[lineIndex]) {
        return this.__lineHeights[lineIndex];
      }

      var line = this._textLines[lineIndex],
          maxHeight = this._getHeightOfChar(ctx, lineIndex, 0);

      for (var i = 1, len = line.length; i <= len; i++) {
        var currentCharHeight = this._getHeightOfChar(ctx, lineIndex, i);
        if (currentCharHeight > maxHeight) {
          maxHeight = currentCharHeight;
        }
      }
      this.__lineHeights[lineIndex] = maxHeight * this.lineHeight * this._fontSizeMult;
      return this.__lineHeights[lineIndex];
    };

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.add(new fabric.IText.fromObject(text));
```

```html
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js" ></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=400 style="height:500px;width:500px;"></canvas>
```